# Why is it impossible to convert const X to X &?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'm trying to understand and achieve const correctness on a Tetris Project.

Here is a recurrent problem that i have when i'm trying to add const where I think it's necessary.

I have a (Piece) class, and one of it's class private member is

```
Point rotationCenter;
```

And I'm trying to write a getter like this:

```
inline Point & Piece::getRotationCenter() const
{
  return rotationCenter;
}
```

Before, I had the same getter, but not as a const function, and was working. Now, I got the C2240 error "impossible to convert const Point to Point &".

What should I do to correct this? Should I leave `getRotationCenter` without `const` ?

PS : I read https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness as tutorial.

Comment: It compiles. Can you explain why Const Point& is working?

Comment: Or, if `rotationCenter` _really_ is modifiable in a const object, it must be declared `mutable`.  This is unlikely in your case, because you should almost certainly be returning `Point const &` (or `const Point &`, as it is often written).

Comment: In fact, I won't be working with const objects on this (school) project. And the teacher didn't asked for const correctness. But I would like to achieve it anyway. So, okay for const Point & ! Thanks.

Comment: @TanguyLabradorRuiz Does `getPositions()` return a reference to data member? Then it has to return a reference to const (i.e. `const std::vector<Point> &`) if it's const member function. Then the returned reference can't be set to `allPositions` which is a reference to non-const. Basically I think it's impossible if `getPositions()` return a reference to a data member; because `getAllPositions()` will get that reference and modify on it. As the result the data member will be modified. This violates the promise of const member function as I said in my answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, getPositions returns a reference to a data member. What can I do then? How can I achieve const correctness?

Comment: @songyuanyao I tried this `inline const std::vector<Point> & Piece::getAllPositions() const
{
    const std::vector<Point> & allPositions{getPositions(),getRotationCenter()};
    return allPositions;
} ` but then i had the following error: "'impossible to convert 'initializer list' to 'const std::vector<Point,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
with
[
    _Ty=Point
]"

Comment: `const std::vector<Point> & allPositions{getPositions(),getRotationCenter()};` ? You must mean `const std::vector<Point> & allPositions{getPositions()};`.

Comment: No, the purpose of this function is to merge the rotation center and it's relative positions. rotationCenter and positions are thow data member.

Comment: @TanguyLabradorRuiz If it's supposed to modify the data member (directly or via reference), then don't make it const.

Comment: @songyuanyao It's not supposed to modify it. I  would simply like to get the rotation center and the relatives positions, and to merge them into a new vector.

Comment: @TanguyLabradorRuiz To return a new vector, then declare `allPositions` as `std::vector<Point> allPositions{getPositions()};`, and the return type of `getAllPositions` to `std::vector<Point>`.

Comment: As a little note, understanding how cv-qualifiers work with references may help here.  `T&` is "reference to `T`", and `const T&` or `T const&` is "`const` reference to `T`" (except when `T` is a pointer type, in which case preceding `const` is considered part of `T`; `const int*&` is "reference to `const int*`", but `int* const&` is "`const` reference to `int*`"); similar to pointers, a cv-qualified reference can bind to a variable that's as cv-qualified as it, or one that's less cv-qualified than it, but not one that's more cv-qualified than it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Why is it impossible to convert `const X` to `X &`?

Because if it is allowed, the following dangerous code becomes valid:

```
const int x = 0;
int& rx = x;     // bind const variable to reference (to non-const)
rx = 99;         // oops, try to modify the const variable via the reference
```

> What should I do to correct this? Should I leave `getRotationCenter` without `const` ?

It depends on your intent. If the returned object could be modified, then make the member function non-const and return `Point&`. If not, then leave the member function `const` and make the return type `const Point&`. A const member function means a promise that won't modify (or provide the possibility to modify) the object (and its members).

Comment: A const member function means a promise it won't modify the object, *nor will it open a door to the object being modified*.  Returning a `Point&` doesn't modify the `Point`, it just "opens the door".

Comment: With regard to the solution: C++ allows overloading on `const`-ness of member functions. E.g. `vector<T>::operator[ ]` has an overload that returns a `T&` for non-const vectors, so `vec[5] = "foo"` is allowed, and a second overload that returns `T const&` for when the vector is const.

Answer (score 13):

Inside `const` member functions all of the classes data members are `const`. You cannot bind a non-`const` reference to your `const` member data, so you get a compiler error.

If you don't want your caller to modify `rotationCenter`, then you can return by `Point` or `const Point&`.

```
inline const Point & Piece::getRotationCenter() const
{
  return rotationCenter;
}
```

If you do want the caller to modify `rotationCenter` (which I would generally not recommend), write two overloads: one which returns by `Point&` and one which returns by `const Point&` depending on the qualification of the object you call it on:

```
inline Point & Piece::getRotationCenter() //not const
{
  return rotationCenter;
}

inline const Point & Piece::getRotationCenter() const
{
  return rotationCenter;
}
```

Comment: I have an extension of this problem, but i don't think it would be a valid new question, si I give it a try into the comment section.

I had this method :
 `inline std::vector<Point> & Piece::getAllPositions()
{                                                          
    std::vector<Point> & allPositions{getPositions()};
    allPositions.push_back(getRotationCenter());
    return allPositions;
}`

And I would like to change it also to const. But seems impossible, because I do this:
`inline const std::vector<Point> & Piece::getAllPositions() const`

My code won't work anymore.

Comment: @TanguyLabradorRuiz Is `getPositions()` a const member function? If not, you can't call it in a const member function (i.e. `getAllPositions()`). I think it's impossible if `getPositions()` return a reference to a data member; because `getAllPositions()` will get that reference and modify on it. As the result the data member is modified. This violates the promise of const member function as I said in my answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, it s a const member function. Please check my edit of my question with more explanations of my (new) problem, cause the comment section doesn't allow me to write enough to be clear. Thank you.